# While entering the city in the weather app.when invalid city is entered then have to show error message in vue

Tags: vue.js

How to display invalid city is entered into the weather app then have to show the error message in vue

Can you please send the code how to display the error city in the weather app. How to display the error message to the  entering the message........While entering the city in the weather app.when

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Parvathy Renjith,

To help you I need to know which weather app or weather API you are using. The API probably returns an error message with a code like 404 when an unknown city is sent to it. You can then trigger an alert using `alert('Unknown city')` when you detect such code.